# Create folders from specific parts of lines in a text file

Tags: directory, mkdir

I have parent folder includes sub folders. In every sub folder I have folders as follow:

```
Parent_folder
folder1
  folder_01_PAP_515151
  folder_02_PAPA_554651
  folder_03_PAPX_541313
  folder_04_PAP_654123
folder2
  folder_20_PAP_413513
  folder_02_PAPD_521354
  folder_055_PAP_685413
  folder_100_PAP_132312
folder3
  folder_11_PAPE_5313351
  folder_32_PAP_3513131
  folder_53_PAP_3213321
  folder_84_PAP_3313213
```

..

I used the following command to list all the folders and sub folders that contain "*PAP*" and save it in a text file "list.txt"

```
find -type d -name "*_PAP_" > list.txt
```

The output was as follow:

```
  ./folder1/folder_01_PAP_515151
  ./folder1/folder_04_PAP_654123
  ./folder1/folder_20_PAP_413513
  ./folder2/folder_055_PAP_685413
  ./folder2/folder_100_PAP_132312
  ./folder3/folder_32_PAP_3513131
  ./folder3/folder_53_PAP_3213321
  ./folder3/folder_84_PAP_3313213
```

From this list, I want to create new folders and the names of these new folders must contain the parts "three digits_PAP" e.g "055_PAP", "32_PAP", "53_PAP", ... from the previous list.
The list of new generated folders must be:

```
 01_PAP
 04_PAP
 20_PAP
 055_PAP
 100_PAP
 32_PAP
 53_PAP
 84_PAP
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a file (named `list` containing, the following, and you with to create a directory for each line name in file, where the directory name is just the part after `./folder?/folder_`.

```
./folder1/folder_01_PAP_515151
./folder1/folder_04_PAP_654123
./folder2/folder_055_PAP_685413
./folder2/folder_100_PAP_132312
./folder3/folder_32_PAP_3513131
./folder3/folder_53_PAP_3213321
./folder3/folder_84_PAP_3313213
```

Then you can do.

`cat list | sed -r -e 's~[.]/folder[0-9]+/folder_~~' | xargs -I{} mkdir -p «prefix»{}`

- I have made it so that folder numbers are one or more digits.
- Leave «prefix» blank, unless you want a prefix.

---

If you wish to just rename the original folders/directories, keeping original content, then you can do:

Test with this one. Then remove the `-n` from rename, to do it for real.

`find . -type d -name "*_PAP_" | rename -n 's~[.]/folder[0-9]+/folder_~~'`

Note the search pattern is the same for `rename` as it is for `sed`. `rename` works on filenames, `sed` works on files or streams.

The options to `sed`:

- `-r` use extended regular expressions (the dialect of regular expression to use).
- `-e` The next arg is the expression (sed program).
- `'s~[.]/folder[0-9]+/folder_~~'` the expression, quoted so that the shell does not interpret it.

The expression explained: `s~[.]/folder[0-9]+/folder_~~`

- `s` do a search and replace
- `~` the separator character it separates the expression into sections, you can use any character, but must use the same one each time. `s~«search_for»~«replace_with»~«options»` or using a different character `s@«search_for»@«replace_with»@«options»`.
- «search_for» a regular expression:

  - `[.]` a dot
  - `/folder` just what it says.
  - `[0-9]` a digit.
  - `+` one or more of the preceding atom (the digit) (so one or more digits).
  - `/folder_` just what it says.
- «replace_with» What to replace it with, in this case nothing.
- «option» in this case note, others include `i` ignore case, `g` do it more that once (not just first string found).

---

The `sed`/`rename` language is very powerful, though complex. The main parts that you would use are `s` (as used here), and maybe next `y`, these are worth learning. You will also have to learn regular expressions (also used by grep, and other commands).

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Many thanks for all your help. this is great !!! I just noticed that you revised it. The command was missing " ' " before s

Comment: By the way, When I add a path following mkdir -p . It is not creating the new folders in that path?

Comment: Honestly, this is one of the best answers i had on this site. I  learned many new things. Your effort is highly appreciated :)

Comment: @goro explain “ When I add a path following `mkdir -p`, it is not creating the new folders in that path.”

Comment: When I add a path following (e.g. mkdir -p /a/b/x/d) then the new created folders are in the same folder where I ran the command. It is not creating the folders in the path /a/b/x/d

Comment: `mkdir -p /a/b/x/d` should create the directories in the **root**. `/a` and `/a/b` and `/a/b/x` and `/a/b/x/d`

Comment: How can I force the command to create the new folders somewhere else not in the root?

Comment: The `/` at the front tells it to be in the root. If you start with `./` or just `a` then it does it in the present working directory. Or `../` will put it in the parent directory. See the rules for directories in Unix.

Comment: AHH! did you do `… | xargs mkdir -p a/b/x` This will not work, it will create to directories a local one according to the pattern and `./a/b/x`. See amendment to answer (the `-I{}` and the `{}`).